# Refresh of a customized WMS-Layer (with cql-filter) generates a new map instances on website

Tags: wms, openlayers, cql-filter

I've two simple problems, but I can't fix it by my own :o(

My OL-map features a basemap and a cql-filtered WMS from 
my local geoserver (topp:states).

1. The map is just shown, when i click the filterform
   -> how can i load the map befor filtering?
2. the filter wors fine but when i change the parameter and click
   the filterform again a new map-instance comes up in my website!
   -> how can i reload (just) the map with the filtered wms?

Any Help? I'm so thankfull for a "code-supplement" of my code: 
this is my code:

```
document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", getFilteredMap);

function getFilteredMap(){

    var a = document.getElementById("persons").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("cars").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("penners").value;

var filterstring = 'PERSONS>' + a + 'AND CARPOOL>' + b + 'AND UNEMPLOY>' + c;


    var layers = [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
        }),
        new ol.layer.Image({
            source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({url: 'http://localhost:8082/geoserver/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS':'topp:states', 'cql_filter': filterstring},
            serverType: 'geoserver'})}                  
        )
    ];      

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
});}
```

---

I think i can't make it the layer variable a global variable beacuae
i neet to compute the new cql-statement wich is a part of my layer-variable.

Maybee i'm wrong ?!

can you correct my code snipplet?

Answer (score 1):

You could try making your layers variable a global variable and then updating this on its own. Currently you are creating a new map and new layers every time you call `getFilteredMap()`?

I think you can use `layer[1].getSource().updateParams({params});` to update the `topp:states` layer.

Comment: Hey thank you so much! It worked now! I didn't know that i've to use the index of the array to select the layer (layer 2 = index 1). This worked for me: layers[1].getSource().updateParams({'LAYERS':'topp:states','cql_filter': filterstring});